# Lemon Parser-Generator: Are nonterminals not evaluated?

Tags: php, parser-generator, lemon

I try to learn parsers. Because my C skills are pretty low, I googled a [PHP Lemon](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/parser-and-lexer-generators-for-php) to learn sth about Parser Generators. Anyway, the code here should be readable for normal lemon friends, too.

As always when handling parsing questions, I start with trying to produce a simple calculator first.

So my first step is simply this:

```
start(A)   ::= expr(B). {echo "======RESULT:".A.":".B.":=========".PHP_EOL;}
```

what parses the first test:

```
include "mysimple.php"; //include the generated Parser
$P = new ParseParser(); //create a Parser object
$P->Parse(ParseParser::VALUE,"13"); // here is the simple test, just understand the Number 13, pls
$P->Parse(0,0); //input is finished, parse!
echo "finished. yeah!".PHP_EOL;
```

...to the result of:

```
======RESULT:13:=========
finished. yeah!
```

So, everything as expected. Now we try to prepare a step that finally will allow us to handle operations, the `expression`:

```
start ::= expr(B).  {echo "======RESULT:".B.":=========".PHP_EOL;}
expr  ::= VALUE(B). {echo "got a value:".B.PHP_EOL;}
```

When I run the same test now, I expect to see the same output, plus one line saying `got a value: 13`. But I just get this:

```
got a value:13
======RESULT::=========
finished. yeah!
```

Well, what happened? Why is the result line empty? Obviously `expr` evaluates to a `VALUE` of `13'. Does Lemon not care about evaluating? Do I have to do that myself somehow? But how, if I get nothing in this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you not want something like:

```
expr(A) ::= VALUE(B). {A = B; echo "got a value:".B.PHP_EOL;}
```

Comment: Ah, so even in simple cases u must say clearly what should happens, otherwise he just does nothing. Okay. Thanks!

Comment: Strange isn't it? It is consistent with one of the main design goals: make it less error prone to write a grammar. In a sense this design choice seems to have backfired, when you tell it to do nothing, it does nothing, when you rarely really want nothing, you want an implicit A = B (if you know what I mean).